# Variable in JSON Path - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variables, path

I already searched for similar issues but I didn't find anything that could help me yet.

I'm trying to reach a picture path (using JSON format) depending on the material type of the picked element. Actually, my code is built like this:

```js
if (globalData.Material.Mat_type == "OSCILLOSCOPE") {                                                         
  var picture = (globalData.Material.Oscilloscope.picture);                     
}
if (globalData.Material.Mat_type == "ALIMENTATION") {                                                         
  var picture = (globalData.Material.Alim.picture);                     
}
```

But not optimized at all, so Im trying to make it this way :

```js
var mat_type = (globalData.Material.Mat_type);

var picture = (globalData.Material[mat_type].picture);
```

But it doesn't work... Got some exception:

> TypeError : globalData.Material[mat_type] is undefined.

I already tried a lot of things, have you got any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Try to console.log(mat_type)

Comment: We can see in your code that value of `Mat_type` is all upper-case, but the property name is just capitalized. Maybe this could help: `var mat_type = globalData.Material.Mat_type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + globalData.Material.Mat_type.substr(1).toLowerCase();`

Comment: @PeterWolf this has nothing to do with his question

Comment: Yes it does, Kevin.a. ```globalData.Material.Oscilloscope.picture != globalData.Material["OSCILLOSCOPE"].picture```.

Comment: Are you positive that all keys that you want access are present in globalData.Material object?

Comment: This one is working fine : 
var mat_type = (globalData.Material.Mat_type);

console.log(mat_type) returns :
OSCILLOSCOPE
undefined

Comment: The `picture` property is on `Alim` or `Oscilloscope` object. So you are trying to access `(globalData.Material["OSCILLOSCOPE "].picture)` if there's no object with `OSCILLOSCOPE key` it will be undfined

Comment: `globalData.Material.Mat_type` value "OSCILLOSCOPE" seems to be associated to key "Oscilloscope" in `globalData.Material`, but string comparison is case-sensitive in Javascript so is property lookup. In other words, when executing `(globalData.Material[mat_type].picture)`, the runtime is actually doing `(globalData.Material["OSCILLOSCOPE"])` which leads to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I outlined the issue with character case in the comment under the question, so presumably adjusting value of `globalData.Material.Mat_type` could do the trick:

```
var mat_type =
     globalData.Material.Mat_type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
     globalData.Material.Mat_type.substr(1).toLowerCase();
```

I can also see that this general rule may not be applicable in all cases. If it's not a typo, it won't work for the second case where `Mat_type == "ALIMENTATION"`, because then you try to access `Alim` property of `Material` instead of `Alimentation`. In this case you could access property by prefix:

```js
function pictureOf(material) {
  if (!material || !String(material.Mat_type)) {
    return null;
  }
  let mat_type = String(material.Mat_type).toUpperCase();
  for (var propertyName in material) {
    if (mat_type.startsWith(propertyName.toUpperCase())) {
      return material[propertyName].picture || null;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(pictureOf({
  Mat_type: "OSCILLOSCOPE",
  Oscilloscope: {
    picture: "picture of oscilloscope"
  }
}));

console.log(pictureOf({
  Mat_type: "ALIMENTATION",
  Alim: {
    picture: "picture of alimentation"
  }
}));
```

But this kind of approach can be error prone, if multiple properties share the same prefix. There's also a hidden issue with case-insensitive prefix matching in case you use some special unicode characters in property names. Lastly this method is not efficient, because it has to iterate over all properties of the object (worst case scenario). It can be replaced with much safer property mapping:

```js
const matTypeMapping = {
  "ALIMENTATION": "Alim"
};

function pictureOf(material) {
  if (!material || !String(material.Mat_type)) {
    return null;
  }
  let matType = String(material.Mat_type);
  // find property mapping or apply general rule, if mapping not defined
  let propertyName = matTypeMapping[matType] ||
    matType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + matType.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  return material[propertyName].picture || null;
}

console.log(pictureOf({
  Mat_type: "OSCILLOSCOPE",
  Oscilloscope: {
    picture: "picture of oscilloscope"
  }
}));

console.log(pictureOf({
  Mat_type: "ALIMENTATION",
  Alim: {
    picture: "picture of alimentation"
  }
}));
```

NB: To avoid headaches, maybe you should prefer [strict equality operator over loose equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**

*Peter Wolf* was right ! It was a case-sensitive issue

I actually don't know how to promote his comment, sorry for this..

Anyway, thank you guys !

Answer (score -1):

```
var mat_type = (globalData.Material.Mat_type);
if(mat_type!==undefined)
 var picture = (globalData.Material[mat_type].picture)
```

Just do an existential check before accessing the value, for keys that may not be present.

Comment: Also please check with @Tim VN  and PeterWolf's comments

Comment: Im already doing this like 
if (typeof(globalData.Material[mat_type]) != "undefined"){...